# How to use 'good of a' followed by a noun?

Tags: grammar, phrases, idioms

Can you please point out which ones are the correct usage of the phrase ***good of a***? I know we use ***kind of a*** or ***kinda*** but not sure about this one.

```
1. He's not that good singer. 
2. He's not that good a singer. 
3. He's not that good of a singer.

4. He's not that good person. 
5. He's not that good a person. 
6. He's not that good of a person.

7. He's not that good doctor. 
8. He's not that good a doctor.
9. He's not that good of a doctor.
```

P.S. I've added 3 examples just to find out if the profession has any effect on the phrase.

Comment: A similar issue is covered in _Language Log's_ article _As ADJ of NP as_. The conclusion is: _...overall, it seems clear that the of-insertion construction is a completely normal and unproblematic variant in conversational speech, even of a formal kind, and some forms of it are used fairly widely in formal writing._ https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4153

Comment: The 'of' in 'Good of', 'big of', etc, is often called, inside and outside the US, 'the American superfluous of'.

Answer (score 2):

'Good **of** a or an' is an *error*, mainly found in US speech and casual writing. Only the middle examples of each three are correct. The first ones are incorrect because the noun after 'that good' requires an indefinite article ('a' or 'an'), and the last examples ('not that good **of** a / an...') are a mainly US regional error.