# What is the correct usage of “of” in phrases about quality

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I frequently see phrases like “how good of a cook is she?” I would have said “how good a cook is she?” without the insertion of “of.” Is either form incorrect?

Comment: In the UK "How good of a cook is she?" would probably be seen as non-standard  and "How good a cook..." as standard. (There are harsher comments on the subject at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-I-realized-how-good-of-a-person-he-is-grammatically-correct)!) "How _much_ of a..." (e.g. "How much of a mess did you make?") is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Related questions: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549469/how-to-use-good-of-a-followed-by-a-noun https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460489/how-good-an-experience-vs-how-good-of-an-experience https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30011/how-big-of-a-problem-vs-how-big-a-problem

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your question will be closed as a duplicate, and this is not a bad thing. You will find the answer you need by having a look at the indicated duplicate. Also, take a look at the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how the site functions. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You should say 'How good a cook is she?'.

'Good of a', 'big of a', etc, are informal US regional dialect forms, and not considered standard English.

While noun + *of a* + noun is very much standard, e.g. an angel of a wife, a nightmare of a day, things get more complicated when adjectives are used. Using adjectives of quantity is standard, e.g. enough of a reason, too much of a coward. Using adjectives of degree — 'good/bad', 'big/small', 'long/short', 'old/young', 'hard/easy', 'near/far', and so on — the 'of a' pattern is not considered standard English.

Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage summarizes this dialectal construction as “a fairly recent American idiom that has nearly a fixed form: that or how or too, or sometimes as, followed by an adjective, then of a and a noun.”

Comment: Nonsense; they're perfectly fine. How often do you write _How good a cook is she?_ in "standard English", anyway? Are you an expert on "standard English"?

Comment: How rude of a comment is that?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I got 3 votes, he got none - _vox populi, vox dei_